# multiple axios inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, axios

i need to do something like this.

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState('')

const urlAuth = 'http://localhost:8624/login'
const bodyData = {
  username: 'training',
  password: 'traiOA9876'
}
const data = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

console.log(token)

const dataListUrl = 'http://localhost:8624/locations'
const headers2 = {
  headers :{
    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

useEffect(() => {  
  //console.log(token)
  async function getPost() {
    const response = await axios.post(urlAuth, bodyData, data )  
      console.log(response.data.token)
      setToken(response.data.token); 

  } 
  async function GetData(){

    const response2 = await axios.get(dataListUrl, headers2)
    console.log (response2)
  }

    getPost();
    GetData();
  
}, [setToken])
```

I need to do a first axios call, to get the Token from the server. (this part works!!!)
But then i need to use this token in the second axios call, to get the data from the API.
In my postman works, but here i can not resolve the second part.

I tryed this too, but didn't work:

```
const [token, setToken] = useState('')

const urlAuth = 'http://localhost:8624/login'
const bodyData = {
  username: 'training',
  password: 'traiOA9876'
}
const data = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}



console.log(token)

const dataListUrl = 'http://localhost:8624/locations'
const headers2 = {
  headers :{
    'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
}

useEffect(() => {  
  //console.log(token)
  axios.post(urlAuth, bodyData, data )    
      .then((response) => {
        //console.log(response)
        let tokenRes = response.data.token;
        setToken(tokenRes)
          console.log(tokenRes)  
          axios.get(dataListUrl, headers2)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)}) 
        
        } 
      )
   
  
}, [setToken])
```

Thanks for your time and your help!!

Answer (score 2):

React's `setState` is asynchronous, that means you can't expect the token to be there once you call `setToken()`.
In order to solve this, you need to wrap your second api call inside a `useEffect` hook passing the `token` as a dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
 // your getData api call goes here
}, [token])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
useEffect(() => {  
//console.log(token)
axios.post(urlAuth, bodyData, data )    
  .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response)
    let tokenRes = response.data.token;
    setToken(tokenRes)
      console.log(tokenRes)
      //you need a return statement if you want to chain an another 'then' otherwise it will be returning undefined 
      return axios.get(dataListUrl, headers2)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)}) 
    
    } 
  )
}, [setToken])
```

Or you can do what kamal said

Comment: Thanks for your response, but does not works. If i check the network in chrome tools, the Authorization: Token (here the token),  the first time that i refrexh the page, is empty, in the second is full, but the server send me error 400 bad request.

Comment: What I am understanding is you should persist token so that it stays after refresh, or you need to wait till your token is not null.

Comment: This token is random and will expire in 1 minute or once you use it, whichever happens first. A new token will be generated each time you call this endpoint.

Comment: Now i see that with your method if a see chrome tools, in network i see that the error message is '{"error":"Empty header \"Content-Type\" ? I need this information to let you in"}', but in my headers the contet-type is configured.